# OpenCV error while training SVM (bad argument)

Tags: java, opencv, svm

I have created Mat with training images (150 images size of 144x33) so my Mat is 4752 width and 150 height. Another mat with labels is 1 width and 150 height. And now when I am trying svm.train() with these two Mat's, I am getting following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (response #2 is not integral) in cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp, line 715
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp:715: error: (-5) response #2 is not integral in function cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses]
```

Here is piece of my code, can somebody tell me what could be wrong?

```
Mat trainingImages = new Mat(0, imageWidth * imageHeight, CvType.CV_32FC1);
    Mat labels = new Mat(amountOfPlates + amountOfNoPlates, 1, CvType.CV_32FC1);
    List<Integer> trainingLabels = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPlates; i++) {
        int index = i + 1;
        String file = pathPlates + index + ".jpg";

        Mat img = Highgui.imread(file, 0);
        img.convertTo(img, CvType.CV_32FC1);
        img = img.reshape(1, 1);
        trainingImages.push_back(img);
        trainingLabels.add(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfNoPlates; i++) {
        int index = i + 1;
        String file = pathNoPlates + index + ".jpg";
        Mat img = Highgui.imread(file, 0);
        img.convertTo(img, CvType.CV_32FC1);
        img = img.reshape(1, 1);
        trainingImages.push_back(img);
        trainingLabels.add(0);
    }

    Integer[] array = trainingLabels.toArray(new Integer[trainingLabels.size()]);

    int[] trainLabels = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        trainLabels[i] = array[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < trainingLabels.size(); i++) {
        labels.put(i, 1, trainLabels[i]);
    }

    CvSVMParams params = new CvSVMParams();
    params.set_svm_type(CvSVM.C_SVC);
    params.set_kernel_type(CvSVM.LINEAR);
    params.set_degree(0);
    params.set_gamma(1);
    params.set_coef0(0);
    params.set_C(1);
    params.set_nu(0);
    params.set_p(0);
    TermCriteria tc = new TermCriteria(opencv_core.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 1000, 0.01);
    params.set_term_crit(tc);

    Size data = trainingImages.size();
    Size label = labels.size();


    CvSVM svmClassifier = new CvSVM();
    svmClassifier.train(trainingImages, labels, new Mat(), new Mat(), params);
    svmClassifier.save("test.xml");
```

Size data shows: width = 4752, height = 150

Size labels shows: width = 1, height = 150

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mat labels` was defined as `CV_32FC1`, but you extend it with integers from `int[] trainLabels`.
You should use floating point `trainLabels` or `CV_32SC1` type `labels` instead.

Comment: the labels Mat should be CV_32SC1, since it's a classification task, if you give the svm a float labels Mat, it thinks, you want a regression.

Comment: Thanks, it helped immediately! :) By the way what exactly is CV_32SC1?

Comment: `CV_32SC1` is for signed integers, it means your matrix stores `int`s.